# How to get column values in one value with formatting

Tags: sql-server

I want to select all confirmed state value to be  added as comma separated and unconfirmed state value should be added to the same value with `'/'` separated using sql query.

I tried using 'FOR XML PATH' but got stuck with condition. I want to use single 'FOR XML PATH ('')' to get the result. Don't know if that is possible.

My table structure is like this

**Sample1**

```
ID  State           IsConfirmed
1   Karnataka       1
2   Rajasthan       1
3   Tamilnadu       1
4   Maharashtra     0
5   Gujrat          1
6   Kerala          0
7   Punjab          1
8   Hariyana        0
```

**Sample2**

```
ID  State           IsConfirmed
1   Karnataka       0
2   Rajasthan       0
3   Tamilnadu       0
4   Maharashtra     0
```

Expected result is below

**For Sample1**

```
Karnataka,Rajasthan,Tamilnadu,Gujrat,Punjab,Maharashtra/Kerala/Hariyana
```

**For Sample2**

```
Karnataka/Rajasthan/Tamilnadu/Maharashtra
```

Comment: Lookup the syntax using `FOR XML PATH`. Example: http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure or does it need to be a single query

Comment: @logixologist It needs to be a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Confirmed VARCHAR(max), @NotConfirmed VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Confirmed = COALESCE(@Confirmed + ',', '') + State
FROM YourTableName
WHERE IsConfirmed = 1

SELECT @NotConfirmed = COALESCE(@NotConfirmed + '/', '') + State
FROM YourTableName
WHERE IsConfirmed = 0

SELECT COALESCE(@Confirmed, '') + COALESCE(',' + @NotConfirmed, '')
```

Comment: This will return '/' separated values only. '/' should be added separator only for unconfirmed states. confirmed states should be separated by comma.

Comment: How does your solution address this : `Basically I want to select all confirmed state value to be added as comma separated and unconfirmed state value should be added to the same value with '/' separated using sql query.`

Comment: @SuryaGahlot: check it again.

Comment: @sqlhint.com It will repeat `,` and `/`. example : confirmed `Karnataka,Rajasthan,Tamilnadu,,Gujrat,,Punjab,` & uncofirmed `///Maharashtra//Kerala//Hariyana`

Comment: @SuryaGahlot: is that ok?

Comment: @SQLhint.com Yes its working in most of the cases but it adds extra `,` at the end of the result when there is only 1 confirmed record in the table

Comment: @SuryaGahlot: corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably want to see the confirmed and unconfirmed ones as separate columns, so I wrote the answer that way then combined them for the final result.  That gives you the answer the way you requested along with an easy way to change it to how I'd prefer it.

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample1 
(
    ID Int 
    , State VarChar(25)
    , IsConfirmed Bit 
)

INSERT INTO #Sample1
SELECT 1, 'Karnataka', 1
UNION SELECT 2, 'Rajasthan', 1
UNION SELECT 3, 'Tamilnadu', 1
UNION SELECT 4, 'Maharashtra', 0
UNION SELECT 5, 'Gujrat', 1
UNION SELECT 6, 'Kerala', 0
UNION SELECT 7, 'Punjab', 1
UNION SELECT 8, 'Hariyana', 0

SELECT ConfirmedList + ISNULL(',' + UnconfirmedList, '')
FROM (
SELECT ConfirmedList = substring((SELECT (', ' + S.State)
                            FROM #Sample1 S 
                            WHERE S.IsConfirmed = 1
                            ORDER BY S.ID 
                            FOR XML PATH ('')
                            ), 3, 8000)
    , UnconfirmedList = substring((SELECT ('/' + S.State)
                            FROM #Sample1 S 
                            WHERE S.IsConfirmed = 0
                            ORDER BY S.ID 
                            FOR XML PATH ('')
                            ), 2, 8000)
)x

DROP TABLE #Sample1
```